# CURL to RestClient --user option

Tags: curl, rest-client

I am sure this is a very easy conversion but I just can't make this

```
curl --user secret_key: https://api.chargeio.com/v1/transactions?page=1&page_size=5&order_by=-created
```

work in RestClient because can't figure out what is the equivalent of `--user` in RestClient.  Tried `addParameter` and `addHeader` but didn't work.  Any help?

Comment: is 
-d '
    {
        "username":"user",
        "password":"password"
    }
    '

Helpfull?

Comment: Allen, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass credentials with  `-d` option

```
-d '{"username":"user","password":"password" }'
```

(this is also acceptable) `-d @credentials.json`
or with `-X` option which adds header to your request